# Add class to a views row tr tag if a certain condition is met

Tags: views

Hello I have the feeling that i fight against drupal currently.

I created a view called "customview" and i want to have the output in a table. Now i want to evaluate some values in a row and if the condition is met add a class called "colorthisred" to the table row (tr). Is there a module which can do this. I tryied to do it programmatically but failed, because i only was able to change the individual fields...but i need the whole row...

I would greatly appreciate any help with that, since i'm totally stuck for hours!

Comment: What is the condition that needs to be met for the tr to be red, is it based on the value of another field, an empty value? etc... Can you describe this a bit more?

Comment: it is based on a field...boolean value 0 or 1.. Thanks for asking